# file cannot be deleted used by another process

Tags: asp.net

when ever i try to delete this files  some times i get this message
**file cannot be  deleted  used by another process** 
even though file is not used by any other  user 
the code  what i am using

```
try 
{

FileInfo TheFile = new FileInfo(MapPath(".") + "\\" + txtFile.Text);
if (TheFile.Exists) {
File.Delete(MapPath(".") + "\\" + txtFile.Text);
} 
else {

throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
}

catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

lblStatus.Text += ex.Message;
}
```

is there way we can assign a  boolean value
**here if  true means i can display an message tellingfile is deleted successfully**
  boolean value   is false 
**here if  false means i can display an message telling file used by another process**

can i   write that  condition here 
`File.Delete(MapPath(".") + "\\" + txtFile.Text);`
   any help would be great thank you

Comment: BTW you have 124 questions of which you've only accepted about half. If you're after a quick answer, suggest you accept some of these.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience, if it says the file is being used by another process, the file **is** being used by another process, whatever you think...

Download [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out who the culprit is...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

[FileInfo.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete.aspx)

method. If the file does not exist, this method does nothing.

***Note***

Also check for any other file handles that has locked this file, close them before deleting the file.

Comment: This answer will work..-i believe, coz FileInfo.Delete will throw an exception if the file is opened.. also try using this http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html to check if the file is locked (and wat process is locking it)..

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party I know, but hopefully these comments will help others out ->

The issue is not happening in Chrome, but is in IE6/7/8 and FF. This method is working for me now in those latter browsers:

```
                    try
                    {

                        System.IO.File.Delete(basePath + assetImage.Path);
                    }
                    catch 
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Move(basePath + assetImage.Path, basePath + @"DELETE\ " + assetImage.Path);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
if (TheFile.Exists) {
   TheFile.Delete();
}
```

?

Comment: thanks  for teh r replay i tied  all the  above still same  issue

FileInfo mfile=new fileInfo()
mFile.Delete()
 some  times the  file gets deleted some times it  gives exception "
telling used  by another process"

Answer (score 0):

If the Indexing Service is turned on, make sure this folder is excluded from the Index list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method which just returns true if the file was deleted successfully, and false otherwise, I'd go with:

```
        public bool DeleteFile(string fullPath) {
            bool fileDeleted = false;

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
                    fileDeleted = true;
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    // File is open **or read only**
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // File does not exist
            }

            return fileDeleted;
        }
```